# Difference between concern and application_controller.rb in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have learnt that concern folder is basically thin our controllers and models. On the other hand, `ApplicationController` has also the same purpose.
We put the common code between model/controller in concern folder and application controller file also does same.

Then what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concern for controllers can be applied to, perhaps, two or three controllers but you may not want it for all controllers.  This is the nice feature of conerns... you can DRY up the code for the controllers that need it, without adding the code to controllers that don't need it.

Code in the application controller is accessible in ALL controllers.

Answer (score 0):

`Concerns` are basically modules that get mixed into controller or model classes for instance. A `Concern` extends [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) module. It helps slim down the model/controller classes, and makes it easier to reuse common code across multiple model/controller classes. Concerns are like helper modules. We can define helper methods in concerns and can include or extend those concerns from various controller/model classes to sharing and DRY up the model/controller code.

On the other hand, `ApplicationController` is a `controller class` (NOT a `module`) and in your Rails application, it is the `base class` from which all of your other controllers classes are derived from. e.g.

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
   . . . 
end

class BarController < ApplicationController
   . . . 
end
```

In, Model–View–Controller (MVC) software architectural pattern, a controller implements business logics, can send commands to the model to update the model's state. It can also send commands to its associated view to change the view's presentation of the model. `ApplicationController` is that kind where as the `Concerns` are like helpers to get their job done.

Comment: Is code in concern contact with model or not? and you say concern are like helper modules then why we need helper?

Comment: The Rails Concern are used to `DRYING` the code for both models and controllers.So, just by including the module, either in model/controller you get the methods and you can call them just like you call it usually as if they are defined within the controller/model. So, basically concerns are used to keep and models/controllers slim/manageable/DRY. To answer your other question, concerns don't contact with models unlike controllers. Model concerns are essentially modules that can be included in Models to keep the Model slim.

Comment: Concerns are used to extract common and / or context specific chunks of code in order to clean up the models/controllers and avoid them getting too fat and messy. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: @HASEEBAHMAD Hope the concepts are cleat now. Let me know if you have any other questions.